# How to add dynamic text to live tile in windows 8 with javascript

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

Well, the topic says it all. I'm dabbling with windows 8 app development using html/css/javascript and I'm having a hard time finding information on how to dynamically manipulate the live tiles.
There is a lot of information out there on how to create multiple tile xml files and launch them after each other but if anyone had a good resource, or even better, a first-hand explanation, on how to create these tiles programatically to, say, make a countdown tile, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't manipulate the live. You use those templates, and push them. If you want to creat a countdown, pick your XML template, set your data, push it to the tile manager. Ever count down interval, you just use different data before pushing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to programmatically update the text/image on a live tile directly in real time.

The only APIs available are those in the Windows.UI.Notifications namespace, such as are shown in the [Sending a tile update Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx).

You can use the notification queue, as [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465429.aspx), to provide multiple updates that will automatically cycle, or you can use an external service, such as [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/resources/#header-3) to send tile updates. Using push notifications from an external service will probably get you closest to the behavior you're looking for, since it will not rely on the app being active in order to update the tile. Be aware, however, that the app will need to run at least once in order to create the channel URI that's needed for the external service to update the tile.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).